# Cypress doesn't retrieve information from the second port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cypress

I have a react application running in `port: 3000` and the backend with node.js running in port `:8080`. I am starting to implement cypress testing but when I try to do a basic test it is not retrieving any data from `port:8080`.

Cypress throws the following:
[Cypress log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqfKL.png)

I have checked with my normal browser the same paths and they give the information normally. I don't know what might be happening... any help is highly appreciated!

PD: The testing code:

```
describe('Login Client', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.wait(15_000);
    cy.visit(localUrl);
  });
  it('Login Client', () => {
    cy.contains('Iniciar Sesión').click(); // a text I have in my header
  });
});
```